# Calling Google API got "The caller does not have permission [403]"

Tags: .net, google-api

Developing a .Net application that uses Google spreadsheets.
Opened a new Google account, enabled the drive and spreadsheet API, defined a service, defined OAUTH2 client (App) and got the client_secret.json file.
Shared the spreadsheet with the email defined in the json file of the service. Later, made the spreadsheet public.
When running the following code I get error 403:

```
Dim credential As UserCredential
  Using stream = New FileStream("client_secret.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
       Dim credPath As String = "token.json"
       credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets, Scopes, "user", CancellationToken.None, New FileDataStore(credPath, True)).Result
  End Using
  gService = New SheetsService(New BaseClientService.Initializer() With {
         .HttpClientInitializer = credential,
         .ApplicationName = "App"
  })
  Dim request As SpreadsheetsResource.ValuesResource.GetRequest = service.Spreadsheets.Values.[Get]("1234....", "A2:B")
  Dim response As ValueRange = request.Execute()  <--- 403
```

What have I missed?
Any advice will be much appreciated.

Comment: why are you sharing the sheep with the client in the json file?  Your using Oauth2 the user needs to login

Comment: DalmTo - please explain